# Crossbrowser alternative for html = $('html')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window, native

Is it too lame to write like this?

```
var html = $('html');
```

Seems that `html` is equal to `$(window)` or `$(document)`?

How can it be replaced by a crossbrowser native javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The top-level element (`html` in the case of HTML documents) is available as `document.documentElement` (references: [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-87CD092) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.documentElement)).

And of course, if you want to use jQuery stuff on it, get a jQuery wrapper: `$(document.documentElement)`.

In terms of cross-browser support, I'd be fairly shocked if you found anything even vaguely recent that didn't support it (and that *includes* IE6), it was actually in DOM1, which was a **long** time ago. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421212/is-any-significant-browser-missing-document-documentelement-for-an-html-doc) on that very topic.

Comment: Seems it should be $(document.documentElement) for the object usage.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, very well supported, it was actually in DOM1, which was a **long** time ago (not that that necessarily means anything). Yes, you'd wrap it in a jQuery instance if you want a jQuery wrapper; you said "native JavaScript" so I didn't include the jQuery wrapper.